# Set up time -scheduler using C#

Tags: c#, timer, scheduler

I need to design/ implement a time scheduler where I can create every possible timing scenario.

e.g.

1) the timer should be able to fire at certain time intervals

2) user should be able to define specific dates.

3) user shoud be able to define daily task excluding specific days or dates ( eg every day except tuesday).

.....

And basically the user should be able to define any possible ( crazy :) ) scenario. 
Is there a ready-made solution to implement such a thing?
In C# you can set the timers to fire periodically or at certain date but are there methods to combine these funcionality?
Basically I m looking for something like the "Schdule Task" in Windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should certainly check out **[WF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663328)**; Windows Workflow Foundation

> Workflow Scheduler Services manage how
>   workflow instances are scheduled by
>   the workflow runtime engine, whether
>   they are handled in an asynchronous or
>   a manual synchronous mode. WF provides
>   two out-of-box implementations for the
>   WorkflowSchedulerService

great tutorial video here: **[Windows Workflow Foundation: Using Scheduling](http://www.microsoft.com/uk/msdn/nuggets/nugget/44/Windows-Workflow-Foundation-Using-Scheduling.aspx)**

Comment: thnx for the link. I ll take a look